# Implementing Laravel crypt and decrypt functions in python

Tags: python-3.x, laravel, encryption

I was able to find the decrypt function with a few researches, and now
I am trying to write laravel encrypt function using python.

I can decrypt using it:

```
class decrypter:
    def __init__(cls, key):
        cls.key = key

    def decrypt(cls, text):
        decoded_text = json.loads(base64.b64decode(text))
        iv = base64.b64decode(decoded_text['iv'])

        crypt_object = AES.new(key=cls.key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)

        decoded = base64.b64decode(decoded_text['value'])
        decrypted = crypt_object.decrypt(decoded)

        return unpad(decrypted, 16).decode('utf-8')


def decrypt_string(str):
    try:
        key = b"xxxx+xxxxxx+x+xxxx+xxxxx"
        key = base64.b64decode(key)
        msg = str
        obj = decrypter(key)
        decrypted = obj.decrypt(msg)
        return decrypted
    except Exception as e:
        logla.logla(e, "decrypt_string")
        print(e)
```

But I couldn't find a source for the encrypt method. There is a source I could find, but I couldn't run it.

[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/bluetechy/5580fab27510906711a2775f3c4f5ce3)

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: I am trying to write laravel encrypt function using python. @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Comment: The source for Laravel's encryption is at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ae041a36e181f7d97927355c3f7c99fbb10c58ff/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php#L98.

Comment: have a look at this source code https://gist.github.com/bluetechy/5580fab27510906711a2775f3c4f5ce3 for encrypt and decrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For encryption, proceed in the opposite direction:

- Create an IV
- Pad plaintext
- Save IV and ciphertext to JSON
- Encode JSON with Base64

For encryption *as in the linked code*, additionally the MAC has to be generated and the PHP serialization has to be used:

```py
import json
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Hash import HMAC, SHA256
from phpserialize import loads, dumps

class encrypter:

    def __init__(cls, key):
        cls.key = key

    def encrypt(cls, text):
        text = dumps(text)
        msg = pad(text, 16)
        iv = get_random_bytes(16) # b'0123456789012345'       
        crypt_object = AES.new(key=cls.key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
        encrypted = crypt_object.encrypt(msg)
        ivB64 = base64.b64encode(iv)
        encryptedB64 = base64.b64encode(encrypted)
        mac = HMAC.new(cls.key, digestmod=SHA256).update(ivB64+encryptedB64).hexdigest()       
        json_string = json.dumps({'iv': ivB64.decode(), 'value': encryptedB64.decode(), 'mac': mac})
        return base64.b64encode(json_string.encode())

def encrypt_string(str, key):
    try:
        msg = str.encode()
        obj = encrypter(key)
        encrypted = obj.encrypt(msg)
        return encrypted
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

# Test
keyB64 = b'MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDE='
key = base64.b64decode(keyB64)
plaintext= 'This is a test plaintext'
encrypted = encrypt_string(plaintext, key)
decrypted = decrypt_string(encrypted, key)
print(encrypted)
print(base64.b64decode(encrypted))
```

For the test-IV `b'0123456789012345'` the output is:

```
b'eyJpdiI6ICJNREV5TXpRMU5qYzRPVEF4TWpNME5RPT0iLCAidmFsdWUiOiAiTlE1djFpaWU1QnFoTWNwRlhNdUFSZ2N3YVlrNG5CZlJyYmRKUGRna3FDcUN6NEZ6ZDhSOHhIUy95N1N3TWlQTyIsICJtYWMiOiAiYmYwNGJjMWEyN2NhNWUzMGFlYTdjZTI4Y2FkYTBlZGVjOGEwMzc3NWZhODVhMDc2MGRhODUzNDc1OTBmYmNmZCJ9'
b'{"iv": "MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NQ==", "value": "NQ5v1iie5BqhMcpFXMuARgcwaYk4nBfRrbdJPdgkqCqCz4Fzd8R8xHS/y7SwMiPO", "mac": "bf04bc1a27ca5e30aea7ce28cada0edec8a03775fa85a0760da85347590fbcfd"}'
```

The linked code produces the same output using the same plaintext, key, and test-IV.

Comment: I can't run it I'm new to python

Comment: What does it mean that it does not run? Can't you find the import-statements? I added them. Please describe in more detail.

Comment: `def test():
    a = encrypt_string("test")
    print(a)
    b = laravel_decrypt.decrypt_string(a)
    print(b)


test()`

Comment: output : can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
None
argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'NoneType'
None

Comment: You must pass encoded plaintext, s. test case, or encode in encrypt_string(): msg = str.encode()

Comment: `def test():
    msg = encrypt_string(str.encode("test"))
    print(msg)
    b = laravel_decrypt.decrypt_string(msg)
    print(b)


test()`

Comment: str.encode("test") (or "test".encode()) will of course work as well, both result in b'test'.

Comment: At first I thought it was working but that doesn't work. I encrypt using python and I have a problem when I decrypt in laravel.

Comment: I write a string that I encrypt in Laravel to the database and when I decrypt with python, there is no problem. but when i do the opposite it can't decrypt the code

Comment: @kaann.gunerr - The encryption in the linked code not only encrypts, but also generates a MAC. This is used for authentication during decryption. The authentication part is missing in your decryption code and my encryption code. Because of the missing MAC the decryption with Laravel probably fails. Why don't you use the linked code, or what does *but I couldn't run it* actually mean exactly.

Comment: Does this mean I have to find the mac address of the server and use it in python?

Comment: @kaann.gunerr - No, this MAC (Message Authentication Code) that has nothing to do with the MAC (Media Access Control) address. You didn't answer my question: What does *but I couldn't run it* mean regarding the linked code. Probably the solution to your problem is to get this code to work, so you should explain what doesn't work!

Comment: @kaann.gunerr - I have added the MAC to the above code so that it gives the same result as the linked code.

Comment: Why s:4:"decrypted string"; return a value like I just need the decoded string.

Comment: @kaann.gunerr - The current implementation posted in my answer is the same as the linked code that uses PHP serialization (`from phpserialize import loads, dumps`), which leads to the prefix (`s4`). If decryption is performed using the linked code, the prefix is removed. However, if your code is used for decryption, the prefix is not removed, because your code does not apply PHP serialization (just as it does not consider the MAC).

Comment: "s:14:"Test";" When I print the encrypted data using dd, I get output like this and I just want to see it as a Test. What do I need to change in the code for this?

Comment: I have to do this in python because all data needs to be of the same standard

Comment: s:14: and ; it looks like the problem will be fixed when we remove the statements

Comment: The first code doesn't work at all in laravel. The second code is solved with expressions like s4.

Comment: `# Test
enc = encrypt_string("Test")
dec = laravel_decrypt.decrypt_string(enc)
print(enc)
print(dec)` returns : b'eyJpdiI6ICJDSm5GSjdnMC9zK3FDRCs3RFk5QnlBPT0iLCAidmFsdWUiOiAiRFhTT2xhY3FPNlZFMGNseEs3VmhJUT09IiwgIm1hYyI6ICI3Njk5OGQ0MjQ0ZTJjMTY4ZmM2Y2I5NDExZDU3NzE3YWQ0NmZmMDMwNGQ1OThkZGFmMDFhOWFhNjcyNjQ4ZGNkIn0='
s:4:"Test"; 
It should return : Just "Test"

Comment: @kaann.gunerr - If you don't want the PHP serialization, just don't use it (i.e. remove `text = dumps(text)`) . But then the ciphertext can't be decrypted with the linked code!